# opening image on canvas, cropping the image and update the canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, crop, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to select an image file using file menu and open the image using a new window, crop the image and replace the old image with the cropped one. All seems working except the last part to upadate the canvas with the cropped image. I couldn't get the result i wanted using the `itemconfig()` function.

Any help please?

```
import Tkinter 
from ttk import Frame
import tkFileDialog
import Image, ImageTk

class Front_window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_front_window()

    def init_front_window(self):
        self.parent.title("Luminance")
        menubar  = Tkinter.Menu(self)

        filemenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.File_open_window)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.Exit_window)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        self.cropped_image_ = Image

    def File_open_window(self):
        file_open_window = Tkinter.Tk()
        file_open_window.withdraw()
        file_name_ = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=file_open_window,mode='rb',title='Choose a file') 
        self.Image_open_window(file_name_)

    def Image_open_window(self, image_file_name_):

        self.original_image_unscaled_ = Image.open(image_file_name_)        

        self.image_size_x_ = self.original_image_unscaled_.size[0]
        self.image_size_y_ = self.original_image_unscaled_.size[1]

        image_factor_ = float

        if ( self.image_size_y_ > self.parent.winfo_screenheight()/2):                   
            self.Image_window_y_ =  self.parent.winfo_screenheight()/2
        else:
            self.Image_window_y_ = self.image_size_y_  

        self.Image_window_x_ = int(self.Image_window_y_ * float(self.image_size_x_) / float(self.image_size_y_))

        self.canavas_x_ = self.Image_window_x_
        self.canavas_y_ = self.Image_window_y_

        self.original_image_scaled_ = self.Scale_image( self.original_image_unscaled_ , self.canavas_x_, self.canavas_y_)   # scalign should not be too much, check relative to size of the image

        self.image_open_window = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.image_open_window.geometry(("+%d+%d")%(self.Image_window_x_,self.Image_window_y_))
        self.photo_image_ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original_image_scaled_)
        self.image_canavas_ = Tkinter.Canvas(self.image_open_window, bg="white", height=self.canavas_y_, width=self.canavas_x_)
        self.image_canavas_.pack()
        self.image_on_canvas_ = self.image_canavas_.create_image(self.canavas_x_/2,self.canavas_y_/2,image=self.photo_image_)
        crop_button_ = Tkinter.Button(self.image_open_window, text = "crop", width = 14, command = self.Crop_image)
        crop_button_.pack()

        self.rect = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None
        self.end_x = None
        self.end_y = None

        self.image_canavas_.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.on_button_press)
        self.image_canavas_.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.on_move_press)
        self.image_canavas_.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.on_button_release)

        self.image_open_window.resizable(0,0)
        self.image_open_window.mainloop()

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y
        self.rect = self.image_canavas_.create_rectangle(self.start_x, self.start_y, 1, 1)

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)
        self.image_canavas_.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        self.end_x =  event.x
        self.end_y =  event.y
        pass        

    def Scale_image(self,image_data_,size_x,size_y):
        return image_data_.resize((size_x,size_y),Image.ANTIALIAS)

    def Crop_image(self):
        self.cropped_image_ = self.original_image_scaled_.crop((self.start_x,self.start_y,self.end_x,self.end_y))
        self.cropped_photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.cropped_image_)
        self.image_canavas_.delete(self.rect)
        self.image_open_window.configure(width=self.cropped_image_.size[0],height = self.cropped_image_.size[1])
        self.image_canavas_.configure(width=self.cropped_image_.size[0],height=self.cropped_image_.size[1])
        self.image_canavas_.create_image(self.cropped_image_.size[0]/2,self.cropped_image_.size[1]/2,image=self.cropped_photoimage )

    def Exit_window(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

def main():

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+300+300")
    app = Front_window(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the result that you're getting, and how is it different than what you want? Does the program crash? Do you get an error? Does the wrong image show up?

Comment: When i press the crop button, the screen become empty. The program does not crush and no error is displayed.

Comment: It is working now as i want it. But i don't feel like it is quite the right way.If someone could comment on the Crop_image function, it would be very nice.